# SSRS subreport giving error "verify suvreport has been published"

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

The subreport on previewing is giving an error as:

> Subreport could not be found at the specified location. Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct

When I just preview the subreport , it works fine but when I run the main report in which I have added the subreport , it gives the error as above.

Also, I deployed the main report and running on report server does not give any error but when I preview it locally in Visual Studio it gives that error.

What could be the issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure you have the subreport locally on your PC, in the same folder as the main report?

Comment: Yes I did . It is resolved though . I believe it was caching so was not loading . I restarted and refreshed and it ran successfully.